# What is meaning by space name in Google Hangout API

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

`GET https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/{name=spaces/*}`

Example: spaces/AAAAMpdlehY

From where I can check my space name.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Space is the chat room, it has the following properties:

```
{
  "name": string,
  "type": enum (Type),
  "displayName": string
}
```

Sample:

```
"spaces": [
    {
      "name": "spaces/1qI6WgAAAAE",
      "type": "DM",
      "displayName": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "spaces/AAAAA-kdsi4",
      "type": "ROOM",
      "displayName": "test room"
    },
  ]
```

- The spaces of the type `ROOM` are the ones you created and they have the `displayName` that you assigned to them.
- The spaces of the type `DM` are chatrooms between a user and a bot, they do not have a display name and appear in the user interface of `https://chat.google.com/` as conversations under the section `BOTS`
- `name` is a parameter that gets assigned to a space in the background when it gets created.

### How to retrieve space names?

The easiest way is to write a `function onMessage()` and retrieve the details of the room where a message was sent as an event object.

Apps Script sample:

```
function onMessage(event) {
  var name = event.space.name;
  var displayName = event.space.displayName;
  Logger.log(name);
  Logger.log(displayName);
}
```

- If you want to list all spaces independently of an event, you need to use the method [spaces:list](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/list).
- Mind that this can only be done with a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

The Space Name is an unique identifier for a conversation.

Space is of two types:

- Room
- Direct Message

  Any Information regarding a room or a Direct Message can be got only using Space Name.

The Space Name can be found in the Last part of the URL.
For Example: chat.google.com/room/AABBCCxh8

Here `AABBCCxh8` is the Space Name.